# ArrayList duplicates last edited recyclerview item after app closes and opens KOTLIN

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

When the last item of a recyclerview is modified. The information of that last item is then duplicated onto the other items. For example, say you type Car, train and plane. After closing the app and opening it. You'll find that they all the items now display plane.

**My Modifiying function**

```
 @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
fun modifyTask(taskPosition: String, taskTitle: String, taskText: String) {
    val target = list[taskPosition.toInt()]

    target.title = taskTitle
    target.text = taskText

    val values = ContentValues()

    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.US)
    val date = sdf.format(Date())

    values.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.ID, taskPosition)
    values.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE, taskTitle)
    values.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TEXT, taskText)
    values.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_DATE, date)

    val db = mHelper.readableDatabase
    db.update(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE,  values, TaskContract.TaskEntry.ID + "=" + target.ID, null)
    db.close()

    notifyItemChanged(taskPosition.toInt())
    notifyDataSetChanged()

}
```